# Keyup event prevents arrow keys in text field in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Please check this on Google Chrome browser:

```js
jQuery('#tien_cong').keyup(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(".", ","));
  var sum = 0;

  var tien_cong = jQuery('#tien_cong').val();
  tien_cong = tien_cong.replace(/,/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textfield" id="tien_cong" type="text" data-required="" data-type="text" name="tien_cong" placeholder="" value="" size="">
```

I try to replace `.` by `,` when user types somethings with `.` in a textbox.

On Chrome browser, when user press left cursor button on keyboard <kbd>←</kbd>, it can not move.

[image]

Why?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 49.0.2623.112 m

Comment: Yeah, but not with back button, is with the left cursor button in keyboard. It happens because when you replace chrome lose the position of the caret. I don't know how to fix that. Chrome sucks, as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the input is updating every time a key is pressed. Testing to see if the character is a '.' before replacing will prevent the script from running when it doesn't need to, and prevents the cursor from resetting.

```js
jQuery('#tien_cong').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which === 190) {
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/\./g,","));
  }     
 
  var sum = 0;

  var tien_cong = jQuery('#tien_cong').val();
  tien_cong = tien_cong.replace(/,/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textfield" id="tien_cong" type="text" data-required="" data-type="text" name="tien_cong" placeholder="" value="" size="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Chrome 50. But anyway I recommend to change this:

```
jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/\./g,","));
```

as otherwise always only the first '.' gets replaced.

Comment: Thanks. Can you try my code? It changes all the '.', not only the first.

Comment: If you pass a *string* as the first parameter it will replace all instances.  If you pass a regex, it will only replace all if you use the `g` flag.